# Inno command line compilation not working

Tags: c#, process, inno-setup

I'm trying to compile .iss file with command line

```
            string INNOCLI = Application.StartupPath + @"\Inno\ISCC.exe";
            string Argument = string.Format("iscc /q \"{0}\"", INNOSCRIPTFILE);

            using (Process cli = new Process())
            {
                //cli.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                cli.StartInfo.FileName = INNOCLI;
                cli.StartInfo.Arguments = Argument;
                cli.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                cli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                cli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                //cli.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                cli.OutputDataReceived += cli_OutputDataReceived;
                cli.ErrorDataReceived += cli_ErrorDataReceived;
                cli.Start();
                cli.BeginErrorReadLine();
                cli.BeginOutputReadLine();
                cli.WaitForExit();
            }
```

But i'm getting nothing out of it, i'm using c#

Edit:
I disabled output redirect, now i see its saying "Script file name specified more than once" on console window.

Comment: If the process successfully starts, what do you receive in your redirected std output events ?

Comment: nothing black cmd windows with no text

Comment: Down voters, why why?

Comment: That's because you've redirected std output to your application. You need to read it out in your binded `cli_OutputDataReceived`, `cli_ErrorDataReceived` event handlers. And note, that due to `/q` parameter you'll get printed only errors from the Inno Setup compiler, but that should be enough if the compilation fails for some reason (with no output setup binary). [downvote is not mine, but we lack a lot of information, e.g. what's that Inno Setup compiler output]

Comment: I disabled output redirect, now i see its saying "Script file name specified more than once" on console window.

Comment: Now I see the problem. The error comes [`from here`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/ISPP/ISPPCC.dpr#L391) and means that to the ISCC compiler you passed more than one parameter longer than 1 char without initial `/`, or `-` char. And it's because you passed to the arguments `iscc` and the file name. Remove that mistyped `iscc` and you'll move on.

Comment: OMG please add that comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that the output you get from the ISCC tool that you execute is:

> Script file name specified more than once

which comes from [`this exception`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/ISPP/ISPPCC.dpr#L391) which is raised if you pass more than one parameter longer than 1 char with no starting `/`, or `-` char. And that's what happens because you have mistakenly passed `iscc` and a file name to your arguments. Remove that mistyped `iscc` from there. Change this line:

```
string Argument = string.Format("iscc /q \"{0}\"", INNOSCRIPTFILE);
```

to this:

```
string Argument = string.Format("/q \"{0}\"", INNOSCRIPTFILE);
```

Comment: Thanks TLama it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue and the fix for me was to specific the script file as the very first argument.